# For an avid photographer, which cellphone is better between Google Pixel 3A, OnePlus 7T and Samsung S10?

Tags: photo-editing, cameraphones, mobile

I am an avid photographer and want to buy a phone which gives the best photos even in low light conditions but I have to choose between the mentioned phones so which one should I go for?

Comment: OnePlus 7T seems to have the largest sensor and largest aperture. However, it pales in comparison with the S20 Ultra sensor size, but S20 Ultra is not one of the listed cameras.

Comment: Better for doing what kind of photography, exactly? There is no "best" camera. Cameras are tools. Some tools are better suited to certain types of tasks, other tools are better suited to other types of tasks.

Comment: I read that OnePlus phones spy on you. They are a Chinese company. https://www.chrisdcmoore.co.uk/post/oneplus-analytics/

Comment: Do the subjects let you use long exposures or flash ?  Because that's what I'd be thinking about for any low light situation before anything else : the subjects, lighting and exposure times possible.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/119858/56352). If photos or photography is important to you I would highly recommend almost every small camera over a phone. Pretty much every small camera lets you change settings like aperture and shutter speed. I also find a camera much more enjoyable to use than a smartphone. Smartphones also tend to brake faster since they dont offer any kind of real grip and are picken up much more often. How long do we stick to one phone? I cant remember that I sticked to a phone longer than four years but I still love my old Nikon which I got in 2007.

In my expectation phones also alter your image based on optimization algorithms which you might not like. A real camera might give you more control over your image. (I dont have any particular models in my mind - I just compare my phone versus my cameras for photography for myself to answer this).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a good rangefinder.  They are small and the image quality will be much higher than using a phone.   I know that isn't what you were asking for but I am not a fan of phone cameras.